# Can I use SkyDemon as a passenger on a commercial flight?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation

Could I use [SkyDemon](https://www.skydemon.aero/) as a passenger on a commercial flight in an A320 or similar? Would doing so break any laws or safety regulations, assuming I set the callsign correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SkyDemon on its own does not transmit your callsign or type. The reason you enter your aircraft details is for your own benefit of being able to store weight and balance info, fuel burn etc so some calculations can be done for you in the app itself.

So long as you follow the instructions of the crew, with regard to usage of personal electronic devices in this case, you will not be breaking any regulation.

For what its worth, I almost always have SkyDemon running when I'm departing or arriving back to the UK on a commercial flight, because yes I'm a geek :D and I can usually spot places I'm familiar with using a bit of location awareness.

Comment: Hey Jamie, well it's interesting you say that, because when I landed at Popham recently, they said "make sure you change your Sky Echo call sign as it doesn't match your aircraft"... Now I don't have a sky echo, but I did have Safesky and skydemon running. I wonder which one they "saw" me on...

Comment: @cloud Safesky for sure